# KIBANA Split Bar Chart using Sub-Aggregation bucket issue

Tags: elasticsearch, charts, kibana, aggregation, bucket

I am trying to sub-group orders per stock label (e.g: USD/CAD) and then to display its orders' price.

I split the orders chart per sub-group. The sub-group works partially, it doesn't show the right number of orders inside (every sub-group Label should have 40 orders inside but it display 80 orders). Also, the price of each order inside is not displaying the correct price.

So the 2 issues are:

1. The price of each order inside each sub-group is wrong. They display all the equal same value which is not the correct price. The picture below shows the JSON input data with the correct order price that should be displayed. How can I display the correct value?
2. And the second issue is the sub-groups show more orders then it should. I have 40 orders inside each label and the number of orders displayed is 80 per sub-group.

Still cant get it after aggregating first per order id, then per Label and in the end summing per order price.

After trying the fix, the price keeps displaying the wrong price per order and also don`t expand the 6 labels as the picture below shows

Comment: You should be aggregating by Orders.Id first, then label and finally sum the prices within each bucket

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I've tried the fix by aggregating first by Order.Id, then Label and summing the prices, but still can`t do it the way I was expecting to. I edited the post above with the picture the show that shows the result of applying the fix. Would I still be doing anything wrong?

Comment: Can you post your index mapping?

Comment: I edited above with the index structure. Is this what you would like to see?

Comment: Does the index structure answer your question?

Comment: Can you post the output of GET /orderbookindex

Comment: oh ok, got it. I posted above the output as asked

Comment: Does it have anything that prevents the right aggregation in Kibana?

Comment: The problem is possibly coming from the ordering of your terms aggregation. As noted in the Terms aggregation docs, the doc counts are approximate when you use multiple shards. You can verify if that is the problem using a single shard for the index.

Comment: I meant size parameter not ordering

Comment: One more thing is that you will need to map yours orders field as nested type for accurate results https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html

Comment: Hey man, thanks for the answer. I will look carefully on the subject. Regarding nested types I believe Kibana does not support aggregation of nested types [kibana nested types support](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/nested-objects.html) but I will check. I still didn't find a solution for it, even after mapping fields

Comment: Yeah you would have to use Vega in kibana to do what you want